# Dots won't inline and list won't center

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create the CREATIVE EVENTS hr looking thing in css on this page: http://www.wix.com/website-template/view/html/689?utm_content=ma_html_fwt_temp_1_4creaeven&utm_medium=template_banner&utm_campaign=ma_fwt&utm_source=freewebsitetemplates&experiment_id=ma_html_fwt_temp_1_4creaeven&utm_term=services

However, I am only getting a result which looks a bit off from it :(

Can anyone help?

Here is my code so far:

```
<ul id="hr">
    <li id="dot"></li>
    <li class="random_thing">....................<bold>CLIFFEDGE</bold> STUDIOS....................</li>
    <li id="dot"></li>
</ul>

#hr {
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
}

#hr li {
display: inline-block;
}

#dot {
border-radius: 15px;
background-color: black;
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2VkNk/

Thanks!

Comment: You can't use the same ID more than once in an instance.  Try changing it to classes.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides : i dont see any downvote...but `suckers`...seriously!!!!???

Comment: I changed it to class, that solves the ID conflict issue, however i still can't seem to get the dots to be inline with eachother as well as centering the list

Comment: @Mayank haha, just had a strong coffee sorry man:) but yeah there was a downvote. It just pisses me off when they downvote a question that obviously is OK written.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides, I've got to agree with Mayank on this one: no need.  Although I didn't downvote the question, there are plenty of people who might on the strength of the question.  Don't forget that [Stack Overflow is intended as a place to answer general programming questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) rather than help very finite/specific problems.  It also [appears to be a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vertical+align+inline) so there's any number of reasons someone else might have thought it best to down-vote.

Comment: hey i got punished, someone got pissed by my language and is downvoting all my questions now. just great

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Ouch mate.  This place can be a little fickle..  Might be worth deleting the comment if you can?  Also: going through the review channel (top-right) is a great way to boost your reputation, also a great way of contributing to the site!

Comment: nah its actually fun, i think its the "sucker". I'm leaving it on. Sorry for hi-jacking the question and thanks im gonna go through the review channel. Buh bye!

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things you probably need to look at in this example.

**Firstly**: you can't reuse the same `ID` on-page, so I've switched the references to classes instead.

**Secondly**: there are a few different options when it comes to aligning elements horizontally.  In your instance using `display: inline-block` you can simply set `vertical-align: middle`.  [Here's some good reading on the subject](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/).

**Thirdly**: really as more of a final comment/aside: the example you linked to actually appears to be using background images so fair-play to you trying to use a more suitable development method!

You can see [my updated Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2VkNk/1/).

Code is:

```html
<ul id="hr">
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="random_thing">....................<bold>CLIFFEDGE</bold> STUDIOS....................</li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
</ul>
```

```css
#hr {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}

#hr li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dot {
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: This is suiting me pretty well! :D However, I would like to ask how to center the entire list in the middle of the page?

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Vertically aligning the entire item on the page is a bit of a different question but take a look at my [previous answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315493/css-vertically-align-div-while-maintaining-aspect-ratio/20315604#20315604) (and the other answers to that question) to get an idea!

Comment: Im trying to do the same with the width and margins, but its not working :s

Answer (score 0):

I changed your example a little bit: works for me:

```
 <ul id="hr">
<li id="dot"></li>
<li id="smalldots">....................</li>
<li class="random_thing"><b>CLIFFEDGE</b> STUDIOS</li>
<li id="smalldots">....................</li>
<li id="dot"></li>
```

```
<style type="text/css">
#hr {
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
font-size: 18px;
}
#hr li {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}

#smalldots {
height: 10px;
margin-top: -5px;
}

#dot {
border-radius: 15px;
background-color: black;
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
margin-top: 2px;
}
</style>
```